# jQuery UI. Push Slider values into blocks after create

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to push range slider values into 2 blocks after create.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#slider-range").slider({
    step: 10,
    range: true,
    min: 10,
    max: 500,
    values: [100, 400],
    create: function(event, ui) {
        $('#minResult').text(ui.values[0]+'$');
        $('#maxResult').text(ui.values[1]+'$');
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $('#minResult').text(ui.values[0]+'$');
        $('#maxResult').text(ui.values[1]+'$');
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $('#priceMin').val(ui.values[0]);
        $('#priceMax').val(ui.values[1]);
        calcItems();
    }
});
});
```

Slide and Stop callbacks works fine, but Create doesn't work. Conosole.log(ui) return undefined. Help please)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From jQuery slider docs of `create` event:

> Note: The ui object is empty but included for consistency with other
>   events.

Ref: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-create

You can get directly the values from the slider UI object using:

```
$("#slider-range").slider("values")[0];
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        step: 10,
        range: true,
        min: 10,
        max: 500,
        values: [100, 400],
        create: function (event, ui) {
            $('#minResult').val($("#slider-range").slider("values")[0] + '$');
            $('#maxResult').val($("#slider-range").slider("values")[1] + '$');
        },
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $('#minResult').val(ui.values[0] + '$');
            $('#maxResult').val(ui.values[1] + '$');
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {

        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/gFLsz/